# Cascading dropdown list in asp .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, ado.net, cascadingdropdown

All guids
I try using cascade dropdown lists States and Cities but return "undefined"
Model file States.cs :
[image]

Model file Cities.cs :
[image]

controller:
[image]

view file Cities.cshtml :
[image]

cities table:
[image]

states table:
[image]

after run project and select a state show this result:
[image]

Comment: Hi, you should post your code as plain text (you have tools to set it as code in the StackOverflow text editor) and not as picture. This helps other run or try out your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Please add `console.log(cities)` to check the response:

```
$.each(data, function (i, cities) {
    console.log(cities); //add this...
    items += "<option value='" + cities["citiesId"] + "'>" + cities["cityName"] + "</option>";
});
```

Then you will find the property name in response is **camel case**.

So you need change code like below(e.g change `cities["CitiesId"]` to `cities["citiesId"]`):

```
items += "<option value='" + cities["citiesId"] + "'>" + cities["cityName"] + "</option>";
```